# VSCode word wrap is always a character off

Tags: visual-studio-code, word-wrap

I'm editing a line of text in a `.tex` file with word wrap turned on.  When I reach the end of a line, it goes beyond the visible width of the editor by a single character so that the word wrap seems just slightly miscalculated.  It means that I often need to scroll left or right by a single character in order to view the far left or right edge of the text.

I suspect it's because I have the minimap up in the editor -- when that's closed, the word-wrap seems to calculate the screen width accurately.

Is there some way to keep the minimap up and correct the screen width calculation for word wrapping?

---

Edit: Possibly useful information, when I zoom out, I no longer need to scroll left-right.  However, when I reset the zoom to its normal setting, the problem is still there.  I just mention this to point out that there is some kind of problem with the calculations, but at the default zoom level, the problem is present (so the problem is not, for instance, that I have unwittingly zoomed in).

---

Here's my user settings, in case that helps:

```
{
    "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
    
    "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
    
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "",
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    },
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "emmet.preferences": {
        "output.inlineBreak": 1,
        "format.forceIndentationForTags": [
          "div"
        ]
      },

    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "html.format.wrapLineLength": 100,
    "[html]": {
      "editor.minimap.maxColumn": 100,
      "editor.wordWrap": "bounded"
    },
    "notebook.cellToolbarVisibility": "hover",
    "notebook.showFoldingControls": "always",
    "workbench.statusBar.visible": false,
    "explorer.compactFolders": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "jupyter.askForKernelRestart": false,
    "editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedCharacters": {
      " ": true
    },
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off"
    
}
```

(some parts that I couldn't imagine being relevant have been removed)

Comment: Only for .tex files, or other types as well?

Comment: @Berend Good question, it's been so long since I edited another file type I forgot to check!  Yes, also for `.java` and `.py` so I'd assume this is an issue for any text file.

Comment: Are you using the default typeface?

Comment: @Yorik I believe so, yes.  But I'll paste in my user settings JSON file so anyone can check that.  I assume this is where that would have been set.